# Selecting a Google map polygon via jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, google-maps

Is there a way to select a Google maps API polygon via jQuery selector? Something like

```
$('.polygon')
```

I want to be able to send `polygon.getpath()` array to server when user presses "save" button.

Or should it be done via

```
google.maps.event.addListener()
```

If so, how can I pass my `savePolygon(polygon)` function to this listener?

EDIT:

I currently have

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {
     google.maps.event.addDomListener($('#save-btn')[0], 'click', savePolygon);
 }
```

and I want to pass the polygon to savePolygon function.

Comment: u can also u use global array variable to assign path
but
sharing ur code will  be better

Answer (score 1):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(poligonn, 'click', function(event) { 
    var totalPath = this.getPath();
    savePolygon(totalPath);
});
```

use this piece of code this may help

Comment: Thanks, that's what I used to have. But what I needed was a separate button that saves all polygons.

Comment: The code you provided works, but it's not what I was looking for. The correct answer is the one I posted.

Answer (score 0):

What I really needed was

```
 google.maps.event.addDomListener($('#save-btn')[0], 'click', function (){savePolygon(polygon)});
```